# Elixir - Mix run example with arguments

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix

Elixir is powered by Erlang OTP, which uses Mix as a build tool for creating and running applications.

I am now learning elixir as a beginner

I can create a mix application from command line by specifying **mix new sample** 
and I write some code in this to learn the basics of elixir and mix.

**exs** and **ex** file could be run by using the command **mix run sample.exs**

I am trying to write a code to get a specific type of number ,say prime numbers between a particular range (100000,20000)

I want to give the two numbers (100000,200000) as arguments to the mix run command like **mix run sample.exs 100000,200000** and get the result in the given range.

Note - I dont want to build and executable using escript and need to use only the mix run command and also not **mix run -e**

How to get the args as input values in the exs file ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `mix` has nothing to do with OTP, it’s pure [tag:elixir].

Comment: yes thats right ... just mentioned that elixir uses mix as a build tool

Comment: Please stop putting [tag:parallel-processing] tag everywhere. The questions you ask have nothing to do with parallel processing. Also, do you really want answers in [tag:erlang]? If not, do not put this tag as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [`System.argv/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/System.html?#argv/0) somewhat works in trivial cases, we usually use [`OptionParser`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/OptionParser.html) for more or less sophisticated options processing.

```rb
["--start", "0", "--end", "42"]
|> OptionParser.parse(
  strict: [start: :integer, end: :integer]
)
|> IO.inspect()
#⇒ {[start: 0, end: 42], [], []}
```

To use these values:

```rb
{args, _, _} =
  OptionParser.parse(
    ["--start", "0", "--end", "42"],
    strict: [start: :integer, end: :integer]
  )
Enum.each(args[:start]..args[:end], &IO.inspect/1)
```

Comment: how to get this as say a range numbers in a for loop , say similar to for ( i=start , i<end,i++)

Comment: Patter-match the result and call any enumeration of your choice. I have updated the answer with the example.

Comment: thanks a lot , this is close to what i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the arguments that were passed to your program, you need to use `System.argv()`. For example, given the following exs script:

```
args = System.argv()  
       |> IO.inspect()
```

and running `elixir so_exs.exs input_1 input_2` (note I don't have a Mix project here so I am not using `mix run`) you get the following. The `args` variable now contains a list of all the arguments passed to the program:

```
["input_1", "input_2"]
```

Comment: thanks is it possible to get the first and second arg separately, like start=input_1 and end=input_2 ?

Comment: and is it possible to use the args as range variables in a for loop ?